# When drag-scroll disable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, draggable

Im using a [**dragscroll**](https://github.com/asvd/dragscroll) jQuery plugin for my website. I want to make a *scrollable-dragable* post feed, but I need to disable link when *scroll-drag*, now on Desktop devices it's redirect to link when I try to *scroll-drag*.
I tried with `return:false` ,but It doesnt come back as working link after `mouseup`. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vrLuxvyx/), with clean code

This is how I tried to do

```
_window[addEventListener](
    mouseup, cont.mu = function() {
        pushed = 0;
        $('a').click(function(){return true;});
    }, 0
);

_window[addEventListener](
    mousemove,
    cont.mm = function(e) {
        if (pushed) {
            (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
                newScrollX = (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
            scroller.scrollTop -=
                newScrollY = (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
            if (el == _document.body) {
                (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
            }
            $('a').click(function(){return false;});
        }
    }, 0
);
```